# How to place a link to a view in the email template of odoo

Tags: email, odoo-8, email-templates

In my custom room booking application, when user book a room a mail will send to the admin. In the mail template, there is an approve button. Once the admin clicks the approve button, it should redirect to the approval form view. How can I do that by placing a link in the email template?

Answer (score 2):

The url you have to compose is of the following form:

http://odoo.server.com/web?db=#id=&view_type=form&model=

Comment: If you're in Odoo 9+, you should be able to include the equivalent of this in your email template: `"{}web?db={}#id={}&view_type=form&model={}".format(base_url, db, self.id, self._model)`

Answer (score 1):

You can put in your template a text ${ctx['url']}  and then render send template with `template.with_context(url=url).send_mail(self.id)`. `${ctx['url']}` will be replaced with url you passed along with context.