# How to place a link in the email template of odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In my custom appraisal application, when admin assigned a survey form a mail will be sent to the user. In the mail template, a send appraisal button  is there. Once the admin click the appraisal button, it should send a survey form view to the user through email. How can i do that by placing a link in email template..

Comment: Are u looking for this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748151/how-to-place-a-link-to-a-view-in-the-email-template-of-odoo

Comment: What? The 2 questions look exactly the same...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place a link to a view in the email template of odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748151/how-to-place-a-link-to-a-view-in-the-email-template-of-odoo)